# Copy something while airodump-ng is working

Tags: kali-linux, airodump-ng

I am very new to kali.

Today I saw a video about kali where the guy can copy anything from the `airodump-ng` page without stopping it. When I try to select something to copy it automatically deselect because it is working. How can I configure terminal like that so I can select something while `airodump-ng` is working?

Comment: Does the person in the video explain what they are doing? Does airodump-ng include any documentation that explains how to use it?

Comment: It is a lesson video but I paid for it so yes it explain how to use but this is not the important thing here :D

Answer (score 0):

Just double click the paragraph that you want to copy then press the middle button of the mouse

Comment: Wow really? I already know that bro, problem is when I try to do it automatically it get deselected because of active scan that is the problem.

Comment: Sorry cant help with that issue just try to be fast